# IBM MQ JMS application with Spring Boot. Getting exception:IBM MQ call failed '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE')

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I tried to create Spring boot IBM MQ application with Spring JMS.

Maven (`pom.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE </version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mqspring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mqspring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <webSphereMQVersion>7.5.0.1</webSphereMQVersion>
        <springJMSVersion>4.0.0.RELEASE</springJMSVersion>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/jms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId> 
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId> 
            <version>9.0.5.0</version> 
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Java:

```
@EnableJms
@SpringBootApplication
public class MqspringApplication {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MqspringApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:application.properties")
@Component
public class MessageSender
{
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${ibm.mq.queue}")
    private String destination;

    public void sendMessage() {
        jmsTemplate.send(destination, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage("ABC");
            }
        });         
    }       
}

@Component
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class MessageReceiver {

@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @JmsListener(destination = "ibm.mq.queue")
    public String readMessage() throws JMSException {
        System.out.println("Recieve");
        String message = null;
        Object msg =  jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert();
        System.out.println("Message:::: "+msg.toString());
        if(msg instanceof TextMessage) {
            message = ((TextMessage) msg).getText();
            System.out.println("Message" + message);
        }

        return message;
    }

}
```

Config (`application.properties`):

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=MQS1
ibm.mq.queue=IDSMQ.REQUEST.FROM.RTPMQ
ibm.mq.hostname=localhost
ibm.mq.port=1415
```

Tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes  = MqspringApplication.class)
public class SimpleListenerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSender msgService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageReceiver msgReceiver;

    @Test
    public void sendSimpleMessageSender() throws JMSException {
        msgService.sendMessage();       
    }

    @Test
    public void sendSimpleMessageReceiver() throws JMSException {
         msgReceiver.readMessage();         
    }      
}
```

When I execute the test cases I am unable to connect to the IBM MQ. Getting exception:

```
org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'MQS1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'MQS1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:274)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
    at com.example.mqspring.MessageService.sendMessage(MessageService.java:42)
    at com.example.mqspring.SimpleListenerTest.sendSimpleMessage(SimpleListenerTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'MQS1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:489)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:424)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6041)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9213
```

Can someone please help me to understand why I am getting above error.
If I am giving port 1415, Why its trying to connect to localhost(1414)?

I have checked listener, LISTENER.TCP is running on port 1415. Why is not connecting to Queue Manager `MQS1`?

I have Websphere MQ 7.5.0 version installed but dependency 
`com.ibm.mq.allclient` points to version 9.0.5.0. Does it create any problem?

Comment: I would suggest you point only to the com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar and a jms.jar that is 2.0.  You should NOT mix any jars from MQ v7.5.0 if this is what you are doing.

Comment: If you are using the MQ JMS Spring Boot starter, you should not be explicitly putting either jms.jar or the allclient versions in your POM. Leave it to the spring boot setup to automatically provide the dependencies.

Comment: Where did you put your `application.properties`? I have a feeling the config is not picked up during test execution so the code runs with the default configuration `localhost(1414)`.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

`hostname` and `port` are not valid properties. Use `ibm.mq.connName` as the documentation and samples show.

Comment: I have updated the application.properties
 ibm.mq.queueManager=MQS1
ibm.mq.queue=IDSMQ.REQUEST.FROM.RTPMQ
ibm.mq.connName=localhost(1415)

However, setting connName didn't help getting same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You properties file should be in below format.

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=QM1
ibm.mq.channel=DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
ibm.mq.connName=localhost(1414)
ibm.mq.user=admin
ibm.mq.password=passw0rd
```

https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/